# `rootProject` in a Gradle module that's imported to another project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my current setup I have **two top-level Gradle projects**:

A library project `VideoPresenter` with modules

- `videopresenter-common`
- `videopresenter-exoplayer`
- `videopresenter-visualon`

where both `videopresenter-exoplayer` and `videopresenter-visualon` depend on `videopresenter-common`.

All three of the modules depend on OkHttp so I defined a version variable in my top-level `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    okhttp = 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
}
```

which I use in the three other `build.gradle`s:

```
dependencies {
    compile rootProject.ext.okhttp
}
```

So far, this is completely analogous to the way, for example, [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) is set up. And it seems to work as long as I compile the modules from within this project.

**However**, I also have an application project that uses one or more of these modules. Let's say the `settings.gradle` of that project includes the following:

```
include ':videopresenter-common'
include ':videopresenter-exoplayer'
project(':videopresenter-common').projectDir = new File('../VideoPresenterAndroid/videopresenter-common')
project(':videopresenter-exoplayer').projectDir = new File('../VideoPresenterAndroid/videopresenter-exoplayer')
```

Now, when I try to compile the application project Gradle complains because it

> Cannot get property 'okhttp' on extra properties extension as it does
>   not exist

presumably because `rootProject` now points to the top-level `build.gradle` of my application project.

If I add the property there the project compiles. However, **I don't want to have to "inject" the correct version number from the main project into the library project. Is there a way to centrally declare the property in the library project so that it also applies when the module is imported into another project?**

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get the value from the library then you could just get the library project's `rootProject` then reference the `ext` like before.  Being specific about what project we are looking for should provide the expected result.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':videopresenter-common').rootProject.ext.okhttp
}
```

As long as the project is in the `settings.gradle` you should be able to reference it's extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `ext` is currently not defined in `videopresenter-common`, but in the *parent* `build.gradle` of that project. Strictly speaking, `videopresenter-common` should not even know anything about OkHttp, because it defines only generic interfaces and should not be concerned with the implementation (OkHttp vs. some other HTTP client). However, your suggestion is a lot better than what I am doing now... So, while not being exactly what I was looking for, this works well enough - thanks a lot!